# Transparent image changing color to very light when used on light background in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to use this transparent image (transparent brown, with a transparent white shadow):
[image: transparent brown front]
over this background:
[image]
in Unity UI.

But the end result is not similar to what I see in photoshop at all.

What I expect and what I have inPhotoshop:
[image]
What I get in Unity:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What color space are you using? Linear or gamma?

Comment: @Kevin Gamma is used